# mysql self join based enum values

Tags: mysql, join, pivot, self-join

how to get count based on enum status using self join

I have a table called "student" in which I have used enum for status 0,1,2 where 0 for inactive, 1 for active and 2 for deleted.

that is

```
studentid studentenrollid studentname studentstatus

1          3                 xyz          1

2          3                 xyz          2

3          8                 asda         1

4          7                 sdd          1

5          9                 asds         0

6          3                 xyz          1
```

I need get the count based  on status where studentrollid is unique.

```
studentrollid | inactive | active | deleted

    3            0           2        1

    8            0           1        0

    7            0           1        0

    9            1           0        0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please:

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8aa5/7)

```
select studentenrollid,
sum(case when studentstatus = 1 then 1
    else 0 end) as Active, 
sum(case when studentstatus = 0 then 1
    else 0 end) as Inactive, 
sum(case when studentstatus = 2 then 1
    else 0 end) as Deleted
from demo
group by studentenrollid
;

| STUDENTENROLLID | ACTIVE | INACTIVE | DELETED |
-------------------------------------------------
|               3 |      2 |        0 |       1 |
|               7 |      1 |        0 |       0 |
|               8 |      1 |        0 |       0 |
|               9 |      0 |        1 |       0 |
```

[**Another shorter query:**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8aa5/17)

```
select a.studentenrollid,
sum(a.studentstatus = 1) as Active, 
sum(a.studentstatus = 0) as Inactive,
sum(a.studentstatus = 2) as Deleted 
from demo a
group by a.studentenrollid
;

| STUDENTENROLLID | ACTIVE | INACTIVE | DELETED |
-------------------------------------------------
|               3 |      2 |        0 |       1 |
|               7 |      1 |        0 |       0 |
|               8 |      1 |        0 |       0 |
|               9 |      0 |        1 |       0 |
```

### [MYSQL 5.1.61 version query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/4a8fe/1)

---

**Based on OP's create statment/insert statements given in the comments:**

[SQLFIDDEL DEMO 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/86b1f/3)

```
| STUDENTENROLLID | ACTIVE | INACTIVE | DELETED |
-------------------------------------------------
|               1 |      1 |        0 |       0 |
|               2 |      1 |        0 |       0 |
|               3 |      1 |        0 |       0 |
|              41 |      9 |        1 |       1 |
```

Comment: im using mysql 5.1 its not getting above result

Comment: no error im getting only deleted count rest count are 0
0,0,29
0,0,1
0,0,1

Comment: I don't have 5.1 :( but can you try this please (second query as per this link)? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8aa5/17

Comment: [According to the documentation, `case` should work for.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html), check the example to the very end.

Comment: Here you go with 5.1.6 version in SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/4a8fe/1 sorry I didn't notice it's there.

Comment: Hi can u please try this CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `demo` (
  `studentid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `studentenrollid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `studentstatus` enum('0','1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    PRIMARY KEY (`studentid`),
   KEY `studentenrollid` (`studentenrollid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=84 ;

Comment: INSERT INTO `demo` (`studentid`, `studentenrollid`, `studentstatus`) VALUES(22,  41,  '2'),(23, 1,'1'),(24,  2, '1'),(25,  3,  '1'),(26,  41,  '1'),(29,  41, '1'),(30,  41, '1'),(31,  41,  '1'),(32, 41,  '1'),(33,  41,  '1'),(34,  41,'1'),(35,  41,  '1'),(36,  41,  '1'),(37,  41,  '1')

Comment: Check this please http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/86b1f/3 it's working. I believe your status is a `varchar`, where as I have added it as an int. Then when you add '' around the status, it started giving the results `=)`

Comment: Glad you got it worked `:)` For `enum` as it works as a `varchar`, you need to wrap them with `''`. Good Luck and let us know if you have further questions on the same.

Comment: i need get one more column with count of status(0,1) how to pass in condition in case statement

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to *pivot* the data:

```
select studentenrollid,
  count(case when studentstatus = '0' then studentid end) InActive,
  count(case when studentstatus = '1' then studentid end) Active,
  count(case when studentstatus = '2' then studentid end) Deleted
from yourtable
group by studentenrollid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/028df/5).

The result is:

```
| STUDENTENROLLID | INACTIVE | ACTIVE | DELETED |
-------------------------------------------------
|               3 |        0 |      2 |       1 |
|               7 |        0 |      1 |       0 |
|               8 |        0 |      1 |       0 |
|               9 |        1 |      0 |       0 |
```

Edit #1, using the sample data that you placed in the comments:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS demo 
( 
  studentid int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  studentenrollid int(11) NOT NULL, 
  studentstatus enum('0','1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', 
  PRIMARY KEY (studentid), 
  KEY studentenrollid (studentenrollid) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=84 ;


INSERT INTO demo (studentid, studentenrollid, studentstatus) 
VALUES
(22, 41, '2'),
(23, 1,'1'),
(24, 2, '1'),
(25, 3, '1'),
(26, 41, '1'),
(29, 41, '1'),
(30, 41, '1'),
(31, 41, '1'),
(32, 41, '1'),
(33, 41, '1'),
(34, 41,'1'),
(35, 41, '1'),
(36, 41, '1'),
(37, 41, '1')
```

Your query would be:

```
select studentenrollid,
  count(case when studentstatus = '0' then studentid end) InActive,
  count(case when studentstatus = '1' then studentid end) Active,
  count(case when studentstatus = '2' then studentid end) Deleted
from demo
group by studentenrollid
```

With the result (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d37b1/2)):

```
| STUDENTENROLLID | INACTIVE | ACTIVE | DELETED |
-------------------------------------------------
|               1 |        0 |      1 |       0 |
|               2 |        0 |      1 |       0 |
|               3 |        0 |      1 |       0 |
|              41 |        0 |     10 |       1 |
```

Note, you are only getting a deleted count because that is the only value that you have in your data base (at least in the sample data).

Comment: @user2018795 if you are using mysql 5.1 this should work see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/028df

Comment: @user2018795 see my edit, the query is working as expected.  The sample data that you placed in the comments only contains deleted records so you will only return those counts. The results are the same when using your sample data.

Comment: there are 11 records for 41(STUDENTENROLLID ) in which 1 record deleted (studentstatus = 2) rest records are (studentstatus = 1)

Comment: @user2018795 should be fixed now. See my edit. It is interpreting the `studentstatus` values as strings instead of ints